# makedirs gives OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/pdf_files'

Tags: python, operating-system, directory, createfile

I'm trying to create a folder inside a folder, first I check if that directory exists and create it if necessary:

```
name = "User1"
if not os.path.exists("/pdf_files/%s" % name):
    os.makedirs('/pdf_files/%s' % name )
```

Problem is that i'm getting an error : `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/pdf_files'`

This folder named: `pdf_file` that I created have all permissions: `drwxrwxrwx` or `'777'`

I searched about  this and I saw some solutions but none of them solved my problem.
Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are trying to create your folder inside root directory (`/`).

Change `/pdf_files/%s` to `pdf_files/%s` or `/home/username/pdf_files/%s`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't noticed it earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to create your folder inside root directory `(/)`, another simple way could be to add `'.'` before that. so say your `/directory` becomes `./directory`